# Why mediaSource does not work fine with some webm video file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, media-source

#### [My Sample Code WebSite](http://scott1028.github.io/HTML5-Videoplayer-Ajaxing-Video-Webcam-Study/askMediaSource/index.html)

1. The first video is work fine. named `success.webm`.
2. The second video is not work. named `fail.webm`.

   - I don't know what's difference between two videos, They are all webm format. but some video can not work with MediaSource on JavaScript(Chrome).

#### This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    function callback(buffer, sourceBuffer){
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
        console.log(buffer.byteLength);
    };

    function get(url, callback, sourceBuffer) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            callback(xhr.response, sourceBuffer);
        };
    };
</script>
<body>
<video id="v1" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
    var ms1 = new MediaSource();
    var video1 = document.querySelector('#v1');
    video1.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms1);
    ms1.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
        var sourceBuffer = ms1.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
        get('success.webm', callback, sourceBuffer);
    }, false);
</script>
<hr />
<video id="v2" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
    var ms2 = new MediaSource();
    var video2 = document.querySelector('#v2');
    video2.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms2);
    ms2.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
        var sourceBuffer = ms2.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
        get('fail.webm', callback, sourceBuffer);
    }, false);
</script>
<h3>Why my secondary video can not be played? I don't know what's difference between success.webm and fail.webm</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my FF51.0beta on osX doesn't support this codec and my chrome 54 has same bug as OP. And the "takes longer" should not have any incidence, the buffer has been decoded, we've got its length logged in the console. Even the MediaSource's duration seems correct, and the first frame is painted ; but when you change the currentTime, nothing happens, and the `buffered` property of the sourceBuffer is empty. Worth to note that when set directly as the src of the video, then it works.

Comment: @JaromandaX, it's now 15 minutes have got this tab open :-) And I was able to read it until the end in an other tab since then. As I said, we've got the bytelength in console, so the dowloading of the file is done correctly. There is definitely a bug in my chrome 54 on osX, not sure if it's the same as OP's one since we don't have any info back from him, but an easy workaround would be to not use MediaSource at all since in this exact case, it's useless. A simple `video1.src = 'fail.webm'` does work, and even a `xhr.reponseType='blob'; ... video1.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response)` would.

Comment: One difference ... fail is in WebM format version 1, success is in format version 2

Comment: Oh, I just want to use mediaSource api because I want my video sent from server by segment. (ex: 10Mb = 1Mb * 10, not 10 video file)

Comment: Well that's already kind of what browsers do with big video files and the `<video>` tag. They just download the metadata, then buffer only a part of the media, depending on which part you're trying to watch. Different browsers will have different behaviors, depending on user's internet connection status, or device. Not sure you can do better than them.

Comment: I am having this issue now, was there ever an accepted answer?